# Show windows horizontally for selected windows in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, window

I know that we can show all windows horizontally by right clicking on task bar, but it arranges all open windows. Is there a way to organize only selected windows?

If I have multiple displays, how do I show them horizontally on just one display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two programs that claim to be able to provide the functionality you're looking for are  [WindowSpace](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html) and [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) (with credit to answers from [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/285356/possible-to-snap-top-bottom-instead-of-just-left-right-in-windows-7)).  I've not used these programs myself.

Windows 8 does not have the *built-in ability* to arrange only selected windows horizontally (or vertically).

Answer (score -1):

1. Place the windows that you want to tile on the display on which you want them to be tiled.
2. Open Task Manager (there are various ways; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> is the easiest).
3. On the **Applications** tab (the default tab), multi-select the items you want to tile by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking on them.
4. Right-click any of the selected items and select **Tile Horizontally** from the menu.

If you have multiple monitors, the windows are tiled on whichever monitor they're on at the time you tile them:

- If you place all the windows on one monitor, they're all tiled together on that monitor.
- If you select two windows on Monitor 1 and two windows on Monitor 2 and tile them, the first two windows are tiled with each other on Monitor 1 and the second two windows are tiled with each other on Monitor 2.
- If any of the windows you select are on a monitor without any of the other selected windows, they expand to fill that monitor's display (note that they're *not* maximized; they just resize to the full size of the screen). So, if have three monitors and you multi-select one window on each monitor in Task Manager, then tile either vertically or horizontally, each window will fill each display. If two are on one monitor and one is on its own monitor, the first two windows are tiled and the last one expands to the full screen size (but not maximized)...etc.

Comment: I think this is for Windows 7? There is no Applications tab in Windows 8.1, and I can't ctrl-select items in the task manager Processes tab.