# Snap to top of screen in Windows 10 on portrait monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, aero-snap

In Windows 10, is there a way to snap to top and bottom of screen (instead of maximising on dragging to top of screen for example) on my portrait monitor?

[image: 3 monitors, one with portrait orientation]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/285356/possible-to-snap-top-bottom-instead-of-just-left-right-in-windows-7

Comment: Thanks @MSC unfortunately that's for Windows 7, I'm hoping there's a better way now or native Windows 10 means

Comment: I've been looking for this myself, but so far I've only found 3rd party tools solutions, like this AutoHotKey script: https://gist.github.com/AWMooreCO/1ef708055a11862ca9dc

Comment: Apparently the feature was there in some of the preview builds of Win 10, so I was hoping to find a registry key to enable/disable it, but I've had no luck. The other, related keys are found in _HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop_

Comment: @IvarBonsaksen I like the `Win+Alt+Up` which wont break Maximise shortcut

Comment: The AHK method that Ivan linked to is the only way to do this AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) from Microsoft. I.e. you don't need to trust a third-party developer and it's free. It has a feature called FancyZones where you can divide your monitors into zones(grid) and have the windows snap to that grid that you have configured.

The trick is to move the PowerToys configruation window to the display/monitor that you want to configure the zones/grid on.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently in Windows 10 (b1903) no native way which allows a window to snap to the upper/lower half of the screen. However, I am using an old 3rd party freeware tool since years which allows exactly this kind of snapping. It is called WinSplit Revolution, and I am using it to position two different program windows above and below one another, using the full horizontal monitor width. Different key combinations (e.g. Ctrl-Alt arrow up/down) can be assigned to define various other snapping positions. The layout of the snapping regions can be defined.

The latest freeware release of WinSplit Revolution is 11.04. It is not developed any further, and it can be found on different download sites. There exists a commercial successor of this tool ([MaxTo](https://maxto.net/en/)) but I have yet made any experience with it.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this link: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/snap-a-truly-slick-feature-in-windows-10/
The website talks of a Native Windows 10 option: once you've snapped your window to the right or left of your monitor (windowskey + → or windowskey + ←), then use the windowskey and the up or down arrows. Normally that maximizes/minimizes a window, but only if the window is not docked to the side of the screen.

Unfortunately, that isn't possible in Windows7, etc.

Comment: First, he didn't ask about Windows 7. Second, OP specifically asked about NOT maximizing, but snapping upper/lower half of screen. When posting answers, please read the questions carefully to make sure you understand the question, and then post only relevant answers.

Comment: This method snaps the app to a 1/4 of the screen, not a 1/2 as requested.