# How to 'separate' a vertical oriented monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I am using Windows 10 Education with two external monitors. For reading purposes one of them is oriented vertically.
On the 'normal' monitor I can use the button 'Windows+[arrow_key_leftOrRight]' to automatically separate my monitor in different sections horizontal.

I am looking for the same function for the vertically oriented monitor, so placing one window in the upper half and one in the lower half. However, only the mentioned key 'windows+leftOrRight_arrow' work and these align the windows either on the left or right side but not upper or lower side.

Does anyone know how this can be changed?

Comment: You're dedicating a monitor to being vertical for reading - Is maximise-window the correct action here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately the built in "Window-Snapping" as Microsoft call it doesn't let you do quite what you are looking for. The closest you can get is snapping to quadrants, to do this you snap the window to the left or right as before but without releasing the Windows key follow the left or right press with an up or down as well. The window will then be "snapped" to that quarter of the screen.

To get the full width you'd then have to use the mouse to stretch the window across the screen which is less than ideal.

The best solution I've found so far is to use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com) which includes the functionality to [setup hot-keys for doing this](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/portrait-mode-and-windows-snapping/?ID=8e0ff0b8-5988-43d9-bd54-4567d7869f48) and I believe this functionality included in the free version as well.

Answer (score 4):

PowerToys seems to solve this issue for me. It's from Microsoft, and it's free: [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)

Comment: This is the answer. PowerToys comes with FancyZones which allows you to set custom zone layouts on each monitor. You can even have FancyZones override your win + arrow key shortcuts to snap to the custom zones instead of the default quadrants.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know how this can be changed?

As shown by the other answers, you cannot change that behaviour by onboard mechanisms of Win10.

You can take a look at AutoHotkey (AHK) though, it has [this](https://gist.github.com/AWMooreCO/1ef708055a11862ca9dc) or [that](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/108780-move-window-to-half-quarter-of-current-monitor/) user-provided script to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not do that. The closest that it can do is to use Snap Assist
to snap a window to a quarter of the screen by dragging it to the respective corner
of the monitor.

You need a more sophisticated windows manager for that.
For a list of third-party products see the article
[10 Tools To Intelligently Split Your Monitor’s Screen](https://www.geckoandfly.com/26633/split-monitor-screen-windows-macos/).

Answer (score -3):

Microsoft PowerToys do the trick for free without the hassle of Shareware.

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys

Comment: This duplicates another answer.